# C# CLR Stored Proc won't Deploy to SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, clr

I'm developing a C# SQL Server 2005 stored procedure that does data validation for my application.  I have a nice framework built, that is working.  The validation methods are along the lines of:

```
private void TestDate() {
    TestFields(delegate (string value) {
        if (value == String.Empty || value == "")
            return true;
        return IsDate(value);
    });
}
```

The solution compiles, deploys, and runs fine with several methods written like the above.  TestFields iterates over the columns returned by a query, calling the delegate that returns whether or not the validity test is passed. I added a new method:

```
private void TestRequired() {
    TestFields(delegate (string value) {
        return ! (value == String.Empty || value == "");
    });
}
```

With this method, the DLL won't deploy: CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because method 'TestRequired' on type 'SurveyValidator'  in safe assembly 'SurveyValidation' is storing to a static field. Storing to a static field is not allowed in safe assemblies.

I'm pulling out my hair.  If I comment out TestRequired(), it works. Obviously, it's not doing an assignment statement, so I don't know what SQL Server is complaining about.  Did I just stumble onto some kind of obscure bug?  (I know what the error means, I don't have any static fields in the SP class.  Just the static entry method that creating the project gives you.)

TIA,
Dave

Comment: quite frankly, this seems (to me at least) to be an abuse of what CLR stored procedures were meant for

Comment: You can call `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of checking for null and "" separately.

Comment: You know that String.Empty and "" are the same thing, right?  Did you maybe mean for one of those to be null?

Comment: I think when I dropped in the value == "" clause, I was thinking of dealing with DBNulls and empty strings.  I realize I already deal with DBNulls in another location.  In one of the versions that I tested to try and work around this, the only statement in the delegate was 'return true;' and it still failed.  @Mitch, if CLR procs aren't meant to do things you can't do in T-SQL, what are they for?  The proc validates multiple columns in multiple tables and there's no easy way to do it in T-SQL (short of writing over 400 tests by hand).

Comment: I got this same error when trying to deploy something else where it was accessing but not actually modifying static properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [`CompilerGeneratedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx) in front of your class declaration:

> This attribute allows SQL server to
>   reference compiler-generated static
>   values.

I know it sounds a bit unorthodox, but is perfectly OK to do this.

Comment: BTW, the mysterious static is generated because of your anonymous delegate, afaik using an explicit delegate would not require this workaround.

Comment: Thanks Remus.  I'll try that.  What's befuddling is that there are 3 other similar functions, all using anonymous delegates to perform the test.  Adding [CompilerGeneratedAttribute()] before the class decl seemed to fix the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks satisfyingly evil (in a good way). A bit of an odd use, and I think "works" would be more accurate than "is valid", but: much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll qualify this answer be saying I'm not too familiar with CLR SPs

Isn't `value == String.Empty || value == ""` a tautology, effectively testing the same thing twice? String.IsNullOrEmpty seems like a better option (however, that's another static reference... read on).

Counter to this, I'd be inclined to remove any static references. String.Empty seems like a potential candidate for this problem, so I'd remove it at least to test if it is causing the problem. So perhaps the test could be changed to only:

```
return value != "";
```

or perhaps:

```
return value != "" && value != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and changed the Permission Set property of the assembly to "Unsafe".  This allowed me to deploy the CLR code to the SQL server without any issues.

Note that my wrapper assembly also had to be deployed using Unsafe in order to ensure "Full trust" privileges.  (Was un-intuitive to me at first that Unsafe assemblies get full trust.)